# Cloud Firestore : can't filter by reference in query builder

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can't seem to manage to create a query using the Cloud Firestore Query Builder that will filter by a reference field. I always get no results.

[image: Query builder]

In my schema, child_id is a reference field on the transactions collection, but I can't filter by it. I tried to use '/children/2', 'children/2' or just '2'. It just doesn't work.
I haven't tried to do that in code yet. only via the query builder.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is currently no way to filter on reference fields in the Firestore panel of the Firebase console.

It's a valid and known feature request, but so far hasn't been prioritized over other work. I recommend chiming in by filing a feature request with the [Firebase support team](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) and/or chiming in on [firebase.uservoice.com](https://firebase.uservoice.com).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will. 
It should be documented though. I spent at least 1 hour yesterday cracking my head at that.